# MVC5 Validator Error With Date and DateTime in same page

Tags: javascript, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, unobtrusive-validation, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have a date and a datetime field in my model :

```
[Display(Name = "Tanggal")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Tanggal harus diisi.")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Waktu Penumpukan")]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime StackingDate { get; set; }
```

Im using bootstrap datetimepicker for DateTime field and HTML5 date picker for my date field.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StackingDate)
        <div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-group date">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StackingDate, new { @class = "form-control" })
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StackingDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using moments and modify known bug for datetime format in javascript

```
$.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || moment(value, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss", true).isValid();
}
```

and my datetimepicker javascript initiazation look like this :

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'
});
```

I dont use bootstrap datetime picker for Date field because I am using HTML5 default date. It is working fine for datetime field, but I got error for date.

> The field Tanggal must be a date.

If I remove the validator, it is working good for date but same error for datetime field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the validator can be filter by id

```
$.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
    if (element.id === "Date") {
        // For the "Tanggal" field, validate using HTML5 format
        return this.optional(element) || moment(value, "YYYY-MM-DD", true).isValid();
    } else {
        // For the "StackingDate" field, validate using custom format
        return this.optional(element) || moment(value, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss", true).isValid();
    }
};
```